# Windows 10 installation media on two different USB sticks

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, media, media-creation-tool

I have created two installation USB sticks for Windows 10. I used Media Creation Tool for that purpose.

I noticed that the total amount of used space is different on those two sticks. The sticks are 16 GB and 32 GB respectively.

Does the amount of the space used for installation files depend on the capacity of the stick?

Comment: Cluster size on the sticks can affect how much space the files take on disk, otherwise when using the Media Creation tool you can select 64-bit, 32-bit or both and each option will change the amount of space needed. Language packs may also affect it.

Comment: The selected feature of Windows (language, service pack etc.) is absolutely the same. Only difference is the stick capacity

Comment: Can you show us the difference in size and if there are different numbers of files? Screenshots of the disk properties perhaps?